# MVC default to checked based on value in item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC 5 project and we are creating radio buttons from database records.

It works fine below but there has to be a way to NOT have the if check in there and either append the checked after the fact or even before.

As shown below, the only difference between the 2 radio button creations is:  new { @checked = "checked" }

```
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model.PaintColor)
        {
            if (item.DefaultChoice == true)
            {
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.pledge.PaintColorId,
                                        item.ColorId.ToString(),
                                        new { @checked = "checked" }
                                    )
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.pledge.PaintColorId,
                                        item.ColorId.ToString()
                                    )
            }
            @Html.Label("Color" + item.ColorId, item.ColorDesc)
        }
        <br />
    }
```

Comment: You do not (and should not be) adding `new { @checked = "checked" }` - the `RadioButtonFor()` method does that based on the value of the property your binding to. If the value of `pledge.PaintColorId` matches the value of `ColorId` then it will be correctly selected (that is how model binding works). And you do not need the `.ToString()`

Comment: Stephen, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I have a better understanding now on this.

Comment: As side note, you `<label>` does nothing (clicking on it does not check the associated radio button. Use `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.pledge.PaintColorId, item.ColorId, new { id = "" })<span>@item.ColorDesc</span></label>` (note `new { id = "" }` removes the `id` attribute so you don't generate duplicates which is invalid html)

Comment: Great idea on the Label.  Regarding the ID, I actually changed to have: new { id = string.Format("RbColor_{0}", ColorId) } as I need to put some jQuery logic in for when the the radio button is selected.

Comment: From your [subsequent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131475/mvc-require-text-box-filled-in-when-radio-button-selected) I now see why you think you needs an `id` attribute, but you don't (and should not) - see the script in my answer to the other question.

Comment: Thx Stephen regarding the ID, I had that coded as I was using in my jQuery to identify if checked.  I have since removed and now looking @ the Checked value, rather than if checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments from Stephen regarding fixing this.  Basically setting it as checked as not required as since it checks the value that it is being bound to.

When the view model is initially created I set the field value to the Default value and the radio button is set as checked.

```
foreach (var item in Model.PaintColor)
{
    var idVal = string.Format("PaintColor_{0}", item.ColorId);
    <div>
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.pledge.PaintColorId,
                                item.ColorId,
                                new { id = string.Format("Rb{0}", idVal) }
                            )
            <span>@item.Description</span>
        </label>
```