# MVC - Require text box filled in when radio button selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to figure out the best way to handle this.

I need to have logic in where it requires:
1) the Amount if a the color type allows an amount.
2) Credit cards if applicable (only allowed on 1 color at this time).

In the View, I had the required validator however since it applies to the Amount, it shows on ALL amounts, not just the textbox for the radio button selected.

I've tried jQuery to put Required attributes on the fields when clicked but seems like when I set it it applies to every item:
   Example:  $('#TxtColorType_Green').rules("add", "required");

**Sample Screen Shot**

[image: Sample Screen Shot]

**Example below demos how it would work:**

1. Red - Allows an amount, but no credit cards
2. Green -  Allows an amount and Credit card
3. Blue - Does not allow amount

**MODELS**

```
public class ColorSelected
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Color Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Color Type:")]
    public string ColorTypeId { get; set; }

    // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Color Amount Required")]  since Radio Button, need to set Required attribute when selected **
    [Display(Name = "Color Amount:")]
    public decimal? CostAmt { get; set; }
}

public class ColorType
{
    Public String ColorTypeId;
    Public String ColorTypeShortDesc;
    Public String Description;
    Public String AmountDescription;
    Public String DefaultChoice;
    public bool? DefaultChoice { get; set; }
    public bool? AllowCreditCard { get; set; }

    public ColorType()
    {
        init();
    }
}

public class ColorTypeRed : ColorType
{
    public override void init()
    {
        ColorTypeId = "R";
        ColorTypeShortDesc = "Red";
        Description = "Red";
        AmountDescription = "Pay Later.";
        DefaultChoice = true;
    }
}

public class ColorTypeGreen : ColorType
{
    public override void init()
    {
        ColorTypeId = "G";
        ColorTypeShortDesc = "Gr";
        Description = "Green";
        AmountDescription = "Pay Now";
        AllowCreditCard = true;    
    }
}

public class ColorTypeBlue : ColorType
{
    public override void init()
    {
        ColorTypeId = "B";
        ColorTypeShortDesc = "Bl";
        Description = "Blue";
        AmountDescription = null;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
        public class ColorViewModel
        {
            public ColorSelected colorSelected;
            public List<ColorType> ColorTypes;
            public ColorViewModel()
            {
                ColorTypes.Add(new ColorTypeBlue());
                ColorTypes.Add(new ColorTypeRed());
                ColorTypes.Add(new ColorTypeGreen());

            }
        }
```

**View**

```
    @model ColorViewModel
    <div id="divColorType" class="ec-radiobtnlist">
        @{
            foreach (var ColorType in Model.ColorTypes)
            {
                var idVal = string.Format("ColorType_{0}", ColorType.ColorTypeShortDesc);
                <div>
                    <label>
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ColorSelected.ColorTypeId,
                                            ColorType.ColorTypeId,
                                            new { id = string.Format("Rb{0}", idVal) }
                                        )
                        <span>@ColorType.Description</span>
                    </label>

                    @{
                        if (ColorType.AmountDescription != null)
                        {
                            <text>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ColorSelected.CostAmt,
                                        new { @id = string.Format("TxtAmt{0}", idVal), @class = "txtAmt", @maxlength = "10", @size = "3" }).00,
                                @Html.Raw(ColorType.AmountDescription)
                                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ColorSelected.CostAmt)  Unfortunately right now if put this in the error will occur on ALL Color types as it uses the same property*@
                            </text>
                        };
                        if (ColorType.AllowCreditCard == true)
                        {
                            <div id=@string.Format("{0}_PmtCC", idVal)>
                                @Html.Partial("_CreditCardDetails")
                            </div>
                        };
                    }
            </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use conditional validation attributes applied to your `CostAmt` property. And you need to generate 1 textbox, not 2

Comment: use color name as a class and then apply validation based on class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why you code will fail, including that your generating multiple textboxes for the same property (`CostAmt`) and the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the first value (so if you select 'Green', the value of the textbox associated with 'Red' will be bound). In fact nothing will be bound in the POST method because your view model contains only fields, not properties.

To have both client and server side validation, you need to use a conditional validation attribute that implements `IClientValidatable`, for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf("SelectedColor", "G")]` applied to the properties describing the 'CreditCard', and those properties must also be in the view model. AFAIK, there is nothing out of the box to handle a 'RequiredIf' for multiple values ('Red' or 'Green'), but you can download my `RequiredIfContains` attribute from [GitHub](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-conditionalvalidation)

Your view model should be

```
public class ColorViewModel
{
    public string SelectedColor { get; set; } // set this to "R" or "G" or "B" initially to select a radio button
    public bool IsAmountHidden { get; set; } // set based on the value of SelectedColor
    public bool IsCreditCardHidden { get; set; }
    public List<ColorType> ColorTypes { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfContains("SelectedColor", "R, G")] // custom validation attribute
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; } // not clear why this is decimal when your view shows the fractions as .00
    [RequiredIf("SelectedColor", "G")]
    public string SelectedCreditCard { get; set; }
    ... more properties of Credit Card
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreditCardTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view

```
// Generate radio buttons
@foreach (var ColorType in Model.ColorTypes)
{
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedColor, ColorType.ColorTypeId, new { id = "", @class = "color" })
       <span>@ColorType.Description</span>
    </label>
}
// Generate textbox
@{ var amountClass = Model.IsAmountHidden ? "hidden" : null; }
<div id="cost" class="@amountClass ">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount)
</div>
// Generate credit card controls
@{ var creditCardClass = Model.IsCreditCardHidden ? "hidden" : null; }
<div id="creditcard" class="@creditCardClass">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCreditCard, Model.CreditCardTypeList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedCreditCard)
    .... // more properties of Credit Card
</div>
```

Where `hidden` is styled with `display: none;`

You will then need some javascript to handle the radio buttons `.change()` event to toggle the visibility of the controls based on the value of the selected radio button

```
$('.color').change(function() {
    var selected = $('.color:checked').val();
    // add or remove the 'hidden' class name based on the value
});
```

Comment: A concern the users will have is the fact they want the amount on each item (or color in this case), vs 1 amount field.  There are around 5 different options outside of the sample I originally posted.  I do have the jQuery, thanks for posting that and all this information.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment about the amount. Your only selecting one item (color) so your only need one textbox for the amount (associated with the selected color). What would be the point of entering an amount for 'Red' when the user selects 'Green' (and with you current implementation, if the user selects 'Green' and enters (say) "100" in the adjacent textbox, the value you get in the POST method will be `null` (or whatever value is entered in the 'Red' textbox

Comment: I have just uploaded my `[RequiredIfContains]` to GitHub, along with the client script (refer edit) which you can use to get client and server side validation. I'll update it later today to add my `[RequiredIf]` as well, so that you don't have to also include foolproof

Comment: in the sample View, the foreach does not have an amount, it is after all colors have been displayed.  Can you send link to the GitHub please.

Comment: Also, I noticed teh RequiredIf is not part of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotaions namespace.  What do you recommend using for this.   Also, I was able to have the user agree to have one Amount text box, so in the example, they would pick a color, then an amount.  there would not be 2 amount boxes.

Comment: No its not part of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotaions` - I gave you a link to both [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) and my own implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-conditionalvalidation)

Comment: Stephen, Thanks for pointing in the right direction.  After the fact (and past the deadline for changing comments) I found links.  I tried both your classes as well as foolproof, which I downloaded from GitHub.  I learned more about attributes, and creating custom ones.  If you dont mind, the javascript files in foolproof, I take it those are for client side?  I added all the foolproof js files in my bundle.config.

Comment: For foolproof, the only script you need is `mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js` in a MVC app (the others are not required and should not be included - they can cause conflicts) - but if all you want is the `[RequiredIf]`, you can just use the script in my Gitub

Comment: Thx Stephen regarding the Foolproof script.